# Laravel filtering models from relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, e-commerce

I have two related Models in Laravel (8.0)

```
Products
+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----+
| item_id |   group   | show_in_website | ... |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----+
|     147 | Keyboards |               1 | ... |
|     158 | Keyboards |               1 | ... |
|     003 | Mouse     |               1 | ... |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----+
```

and

```
Attributes
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
| id | item_id |    name     |   value    |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
|  1 |     147 | Color       | Black      |
|  2 |     147 | Sensitivity | 1800 DPI   |
|  3 |     158 | Color       | White      |
|  4 |     158 | Sensitivity | 1800 DPI   |
|  5 |     003 | Color       | White      |
|  6 |     003 | Type        | Mechanical |
|  7 |     003 | Size        | 108 Keys   |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
```

I have Products related to Attributes using hasMany() relationship, and i want users to filter Products based on one or more attributes. The only solution I could come up with was something like

```php
$group = 'Mouse';
$names = ['Color', 'Sensitivity'];
$values = ['Black', 'White', 'Red', '1800 DPI', '2100 DPI']

// OR

$group = 'Keyboard';
$names = ['Type'];
$values = ['Mechanical']

/* These parameters are user controlled, user can only filter one group at a time, 
but might choose one or more names/values pairs for filters. 
I.E the first case would return all Mice which has Black,White or Red color and 1800 or 2100 DPI
*/


$products = Product::where(['show_in_website', 1], ['group', $group])
            ->whereHas('attributes', 
                function ($query) use ($names, $values){
                    $query
                        ->whereIn('name', $names)
                        ->whereIn('values', $values);
                })->paginate(20);
```

The problem with this query is, If user selects Color: Black and Senstivity:1800DPI, it **returns all products with Black Color** (and whatever sensitivity) AND **all products with 1800 DPI** (and whatever color), **not products which has BOTH properties uniquely.**

How can I write an eloquent query to **achieve the desired function?**
If not, is there a **better way to do this?** (Better modeling/code structuring)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did this was the following:

```php
$products = Product::where('show_in_website', 1)->where('group', $group);
foreach($names as $name){
    $products->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use($name, $values){
        $query->where('name', $name)
              ->whereIn('value', $values);
        });
}
```

Thanks to [Laravel Discord Community](https://discord.gg/9tcuMkW9qW) for helping me find this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the inputs in another format

```
$group = 'Mouse';
$attributes = ['Color' => ['black'], 'Sensitivity' => ['1800 DPI', '2100 DPI']];
```

And then loop on the attributes with a whereHas

```
$query = Product::where(['show_in_website', 1], ['group', $group]);
foreach ($attributes as $name => $values) {
    $query->whereHas('attributes', function ($attributeQuery) use ($name, $values){
        $attributeQuery->where('name', $name)
            ->whereIn('values', $values);
}
$products = $query->paginate(20);
```